# += operator not working with string

Tags: java, for-loop, operators

I'm trying to produce a program that outputs the user's input in a form like this:

input: word

w

wo

wor

word

This incremental build-up doesn't seem to be working.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SpellMan {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Give me a word > ");
    String word = kb.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0; i< word.length();i++){
        String bword += ""+word.charAt(i); 

        System.out.println(bword);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `bword` inside the loop, so in each iteration you attempt to concatenate the current character to an uninitialized `String` variable.

Try :

```
String bword = "";
for(int i = 0; i< word.length();i++) {
    bword += word.charAt(i); 
    System.out.println(bword);
}
```

That said, using a `StringBuilder` would be more efficient (less objects will be created).

```
StringBuilder bword = new StringBuilder(word.length());
for(int i = 0; i< word.length();i++) {
    bWord.append(word.charAt(i)); 
    System.out.println(bword.toString());
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other code problems, the main point concerning your question **header** is that you can not use `+=` operator within the declaration, because `bword` is still null (It will not compile).

```
String bword = ""; //before the loop
bword += word.charAt(i);
System.out.println(bword);
```